# Changing the text and adding HTML to the text of a checkbox inside a label

Tags: javascript, html

Using plain vanilla JS is there a way of being able to change the text content that appears beside a checkbox when that input is nested within a label tag? Specifically adding a HTML link to the text?

I can change the text no problem but setting the content to display HTML just ends up rendering the HTML to screen. So, in the following example I want to make the Terms and Conditions text a link.

```
<label for="custom_field">
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" value="I have read the terms and conditions"> I have read the terms and conditions
</label>
```

I've been through using nodes and siblings and while I can change the text either one of two things happen - I either end up overwriting all the content between the label tags and therefore killing the checkbox.

Or my anchor tag gets rendered to screen instead of interpreted.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Here's the latest code I'm trying:

```
let terms = document.querySelector('#custom_field');

if(terms){

    terms.nextSibling.innerHTML = "I have read and agree to the <a href='#'>terms and conditions</a>";
}
```

NOTE: Due to restrictions in my CMS I can't edit the content of the label directly to just insert the relevant HTML. So what I need to work with is as per the first code block.

Comment: Updated the question with a sample albeit just the latest version I've tried.

Comment: try using terms[0].value. Does that work?

Comment: @Koen No, didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` doesn't work because `terms.nextSibling` is a [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node, which doesn't have an `innerHTML` property.

You'll need to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText) the label's `Text` node on "terms and conditions", then move that node into a link:

```js
const terms = document.querySelector('#custom_field');
if (terms) {
  const fullText = terms.nextSibling;
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '#';
  const tcIndex = fullText.textContent.indexOf('terms and conditions');
  const termsText = fullText.splitText(tcIndex);
  // If there's more text after "terms and conditions", you'll need to split again
  // termsText.splitText('terms and conditions'.length);
  fullText.parentElement.insertBefore(link, termsText);
  link.append(termsText);
}
```

```html
<label for="custom_field">
  <input type="checkbox" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" value="I have read the terms and conditions"> I have read the terms and conditions
</label>
```

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing so going to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add an extra HTML tag?

```
<label for="custom_field">
    <input type="checkbox" name="custom_field" id="custom_field">
    // Added Span
    <span id="result"> I have read the terms and conditions</span>
</label>

<script>
    let terms = document.querySelector('#custom_field');

    if(terms){
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "I have read and agree to the <a href='#'>terms and conditions</a>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I can't edit the HTML directly....although I might try and insert the span you mention by using JS to do so, that might work.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You can use the same javascript you already have but that HTML element is necessary. It doesn't have to be a <span> element specifically.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me figure out a way to do it by adding a span myself using JS. Essentially like @auxtaco's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the most basic way to do it using plain JavaScript. Since you have a text node after your checkbox, you'll need to first find the text you want to replace, and then replace it with your HTML that is wrapped in a new node that can contain HTML (the existing text node can't be converted).

```js
let terms = document.querySelector('label');
for (var i = 0; i < terms.childNodes.length; i++) {
  var textNodeTrimmed;
  if (terms.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) textNodeTrimmed = terms.childNodes[i].nodeValue.trim()
  if (textNodeTrimmed.length > 0 && textNodeTrimmed === "I have read the terms and conditions") {
    var replacementNode = document.createElement('span');
    replacementNode.innerHTML = "I have read and agree to the <a href='#'>terms and conditions</a>";
    terms.childNodes[i].parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, terms.childNodes[i].nextSibling);
    terms.childNodes[i].remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="custom_field">
  <input type="checkbox" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" value="I have read the terms and conditions"> I have read the terms and conditions
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

[Full Working Example](https://codepen.io/Hassuunna/pen/BaBgRQY)

you can add the value by plain js using `parentnode`

then replacing the old text by *cutting* the checkbox using `children[0].outerHTML` and *pasting* it again with the new content

that new content can include HTML anchors or any other tags

Comment: I can't edit the content of the HTML directly unfortunately, hence I'm looking for a way to do this in JS. I'll update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @HassanRaafat You're not understanding the question

Comment: @j08691 yes, I'm trying to understand what he needs

Comment: @HassanRaafat I have an input (checkbox) nested within a label. Without editing the HTML at all I need to be able to alter the text that appears beside the checkbox to include a HTML link.

Comment: Your edit won't work either as `insertAdjacentHTML` won't get rid of the existing text

Comment: I edited it again so it takes replacing the old text in consideration

Comment: wth
why downvoting my answer?